# Centralizers and Generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Suppose group $G$ is generated by $\{g_1,\dots g_n\}$. Let $A$ be nonempty subset of $G$, and $C_G(A)$ is centralizer of $A$ in $G$. If for some $1<m<n$, 
>   then we have that $g_1, g_2,\dots,g_m\in C_G(A)$, but $g_{m+1},\dots,g_n\notin C_G(A)$. I can see that, then the elenents of $G$, that are generated only by a subset of  $g_1,g_2,\dots, g_m$ are in $C_G(A)$, but if $g\in G$ is not purely generated by a subset of a subset of $g_1,g_2,\dots, g_m$, then $g\notin C_G(A)$.

I think the second assertion follows, because, since $C_G(A)$ subgroup, and if, e.g., $g=g_1\cdot g_{m+1}\cdot g_n\in C_G(A)$, then $g_1^{-1}\cdot g_1\cdot g_{m+1}\cdot g_n=g_{m+1}\cdot g_n\in C_G(A)$. I first thought this gives contradiction. But, now I think, even if $g_{m+1}, g_n\notin C_G(A)$, what forces us to conclude $g_{m+1}\cdot g_n\notin C_G(A)$?

Comment: Your claim is false: even if $g_{m+1},\cdots,g_n$ are not central, something generated by them might be. Other notes: I've never seen the centralizer of $A$ in $G$ written as $C_A(G)$, only ever as $C_G(A)$. If you start a sentence with "If ..." you have to finish it with "then ..." otherwise you don't have a complete sentence. And there's no reason to say "generated by a subset of $g_1,\cdots,g_m$" when you can just say "generated by $g_1,\cdots,g_m$" (since not using one or more of them still counts as being generated by them).

Comment: Oh thanks for these general comments, i will keep in mind. $C_A(G)$ was surely typo. I will edit according to your comment.

Comment: Take, for instance, $-1,i,j$ in the quaternion group $Q_8$. It is very easy to generate $-1$ from $j,k$. (Lesson: stuff generated by $g_1,\cdots,g_m$ may also be possible to generate with $g_{m+1},\cdots,g_n$.) One can upgrade this: consider the list of generators $(-1,1),(1,i),(1,j)$ for $\mathbb{Z}_2\times Q_8$. Then $(-1,1)$ is central and the next two aren't, and you can generate $(1,-1)$ with the latter two but *can't* generate it with $(-1,1)$ (and in this example, the generating set is minimal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that any element of the subgroup generated by $g_1,\ldots,g_m$ is in $C_G(A)$, but not that any element not in that subgroup is not in $C_G(A)$.

For a counter-example, consider the subgroup $G$ of $S_7$ generated by $g_1=(1,2,3)$, $g_2=(2,3)(4,5)$, $g_3=(2,3)(6,7)$ and $A=\{g_1\}$. Then you can check that $g_1\in C_G(A)$, $g_2,g_3\notin C_G(A)$ but $g_2\cdot g_3\in C_G(A)$.